# What are the different ways to load a class in Java

Tags: java, classloader

I'm learning java, and in the process of going through the ClassNotFoundException concept, I have come across the term `Class.forName("xyz");`. I know that this is one way of loading a class. My question is, what are the different ways of loading a class in java? When to use which one? What is preferred over other?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432269/ways-to-load-a-class-in-java?rq=1

Comment: I'm trying to load a JDBC driver.I just want to know, how many ways are there to load a class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I will start with the simplest (Here I assume the class definition is available in the classpath and JVM can load it) :

1. Reference the class name in the code. The class will be loaded latest when the JVM finds that reference.

   ```
   SomeClass someInstance = null;
   ```
2. [Class.forName(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29), to load and initialize the class.It uses classloader of current class.

   ```
    Class.forName("XYZ");
   ```
3. [ClassLoader#loadClass(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29), to load class, but doesn't initialize.You can get an instance of `ClassLoader` and invoke `loadClass()` on that instance, which can be a Custom ClassLoader or System ClassLoader.

   ```
   ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("XYZ");
   ```
4. Overloaded [Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName) , allows you to specify the classloader to use explicitly and `initialize` parameter to specify whether the class must be initialzed.

   ```
   Class.forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)
   ```

For `JDBC`, we need to load the driver class as well as initialize it. Somewhere the driver class gets registered with the JDBC Driver Manager by running some static initializer(though I haven't seen the inner working code). Hence we need to use a class loading mechanism where the driver class gets loaded and its static initialization blocks run. Hence the most preferred way is `Class.forName()`.

Comment: just one question... What is the meaning of  "to load class, but doesn't initialize".. it means that the static initializations aren't performed? Thanks!

Comment: @Victor As per my knowledge it shouldn't.